# Heterogeneous mixture of protocol types, including a generic protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

```
 protocol ParentProtocol { }

 protocol ChildProtocol: ParentProtocol { }

 protocol Child_With_Value_Protocol: ParentProtocol {
     associatedType Value

     func retrieveValue() -> Value
 }
```

Attempting to create a single array of type `ParentProtocol` that contains **both** `ChildProtocol` and `Child_With_Value_Protocol`. Is there any possible way to create a function that loops through the heterogeneous array and returns the values of just type `Child_With_Value_Protocol`?

This may require an architecture change. Open to all solutions.

### Attempted Failed Solution #1

```
var parents: [ParentProtocol] = [...both ChildProtocol & Child_With_Value_Protocol...]

func retrieveValues() -> [Any] {
    var values = [Any]()

    for parent in parents {
        if let childWithValue = parent as? Child_With_Value_Protocol { // Fails to compile
            values.append(childWithValue.retrieveValue())
        }
    }

    return values
}
```

This fails with an error of `protocol 'Child_With_Value_Protocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` which makes sense since the compiler would not know the type when converted to just `Child_With_Value_Protocol`, this leads to the next failed solution.

### Attempted Failed Solution #2

If the array was a homogeneous array of just `Child_With_Value_Protocol`, type erasing could be used to retrieve the values.

```
var parents: [ParentProtocol] = [...both ChildProtocol & Child_With_Value_Protocol...]

struct AnyValue {
    init<T: Child_With_Value_Protocol>(_ protocol: T) {
        _retrieveValue  = protocol.retrieveValue as () -> Any
    }

    func retrieveValue() -> Any { return _retrieveValue() }

    let _retrieveValue: () -> Any
}

func retrieveValues() -> [Any] {
    var values = [Any]()

    for parent in parents {
        values.append(AnyValue(parent).retrieveValue()) // Fails to compile
    }

    return values
}
```

This fails to compile due to the fact that the struct `AnyValue` has no initializer for the `ParentProtocol`.

### Attempted Failed Solution #3

```
struct AnyValue {
    init<T: Child_With_Value_Protocol>(_ protocol: T) {
        _retrieveValue  = protocol.retrieveValue as () -> Any
    }

    func retrieveValue() -> Any { return _retrieveValue() }

    let _retrieveValue: () -> Any
}

var erased: [AnyValue] = [AnyValue(...), AnyValue(...), AnyValue(...)]

func retrieveValues() -> [Any] {
    var values = [Any]()

    for value in erased {
        values.append(value.retrieveValue())
    }

    return values
}
```

Unlike the other solutions, this solution actually compiles. Problem with this solution resides in the fact that the array `erased` can only hold values of the type-erased versions of `Child_With_Value_Protocol`. The goal is for the array to hold types of **both** `Child_With_Value_Protocol` and `ChildProtocol`.

### Attempted Failed Solution #4

Modifying the type-erase struct to include an initializer for `ParentProtocol` still creates a solution that compiles, but then the struct will only use the less specific init, instead of the more specific init.

```
struct AnyValue {
    init?<T: ParentProtocol>(_ protocol: T) {
        return nil
    }

    init?<T: Child_With_Value_Protocol>(_ protocol: T) {
        _retrieveValue  = protocol.retrieveValue as () -> Any
    }

    func retrieveValue() -> Any { return _retrieveValue() }

    let _retrieveValue: (() -> Any)?
}
```

Comment: This was doomed to fail from the start, it's not possible and doesn't make any sense. I believe you don't actually even want that, maybe you can show your use-case?

Comment: The fact that you are even trying to do this means that you shouldn't have all these elements in a single array.

Answer (score 0):

The prior comments are likely right. Nevertheless, you could box the variants in an enum and create an array of those. The reference would then switch on the enum value, each having associated data of the right type

EDIT: I didn't bother with the associatedValue, because it seems irrelevant to the question being asked. The following works in a playground:

```
protocol ParentProtocol: CustomStringConvertible {
    static func retrieveValues(parents: [FamilyBox]) -> [ParentProtocol]
}

protocol ChildProtocol: ParentProtocol { }

protocol Other_Child_Protocol: ParentProtocol { }

enum FamilyBox {
    case Parent(parent: ParentProtocol)
    case Child(child: ChildProtocol)
    case OtherChildProtocol(withValue: Other_Child_Protocol)

}


var parents: [FamilyBox] = []

struct P: ParentProtocol {
    var description: String { return "Parent" }

    static func retrieveValues(parents: [FamilyBox]) -> [ParentProtocol] {
        var values = [ParentProtocol]()

        for parent in parents {
            switch parent {
            case .Parent(let elementValue):
                values.append(elementValue)
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}

struct C: ChildProtocol {
    var description: String { return "Child" }

    static func retrieveValues(parents: [FamilyBox]) -> [ParentProtocol] {
        var values = [ParentProtocol]()

        for parent in parents {
            switch parent {
            case .Child(let elementValue):
                values.append(elementValue)
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}

struct CV: Other_Child_Protocol {
    var description: String { return "Other Child" }

    static func retrieveValues(parents: [FamilyBox]) -> [ParentProtocol] {
        var values = [ParentProtocol]()

        for parent in parents {
            switch parent {
            case .OtherChildProtocol(let elementValue):
                values.append(elementValue)
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}

let p = FamilyBox.Parent(parent: P())
let c = FamilyBox.Child(child: C())
let cv = FamilyBox.OtherChildProtocol(withValue: CV())
let array:[FamilyBox] = [p, c, cv]

print(P.retrieveValues(array))
print(C.retrieveValues(array))
print(CV.retrieveValues(array))
```

The prints from the last three lines are:

```
[Parent]
[Child]
[Other Child]
```

While I'm sure it can be improved, I ***think*** that meets the original intent. No?

Comment: If you think it's possible you can show the working code, it's really not though, I'd be surprised if you can do it

Comment: Can't from this phone; I'll work on it when I get up in the AM

Comment: @Kametrixom - thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you're starting out with "I didn't bother with the associatedValue", but that's the part that makes it actually impossible

Comment: Add `associatedType Value` to a protocol and you can see that you won't be able to compile it anymore